# Adding items to a Custom List app 'fails silently'

Tags: sharepoint-server, custom-list

From the `Site Contents` directory in `SharePoint`, I created a `Custom List` via `New` > `App` > `Custom List`.

I added 12 entries and everything worked as expected, the responses were visible in the list.

When trying to add subsequent entries (when clicking `Save` on the new entry form accessed by clicking the `+` icon), the new entries did not appear in the list (even when refreshing the page).

It is like the form is 'silently failing' and I have no idea why.

It is a straight forward set up and worked for the first 12 entries, so I don't know why it stopped working all of a sudden.

For context, I have renamed the mandatory `Title` field to `Organisation Name` (because i have no need for a `Title` field in my form), so i don't know if that causes any problems?

Comment: Try to use Fiddler tool to check the response from server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I had inadvertently saved the `All Items` view when a filter was on.

The 'filter icon' was not next to the column name, however, so I didn't realise it.

The solution was to go into `List Settings` > `Views` > `All Items` and choose the `Show all items in this view` option.

Then all items that I had previously added were shown.